# how to make the text and width 100% with the resolution and the inputs centralized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

inputs: center, width and font flexible.

```
<div>
        <input value="00" type="text" name="horas" maxlength="2"> <!-- center -->
        <input value=":" type="text" disabled>                    <!-- center -->
        <input value="00" type="text" maxlength="2">              <!-- center -->
        <input value=":" type="text" disabled>                    <!-- center -->
        <input value="00" type="text" maxlength="2">              <!-- center -->
</div>
```

Examples:

#### | 00:00:00 |

### | 00:00:00 |

## | 00:00:00 |

thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try to fiddle your code.

Comment: Please explain your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b0jqdkc4/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input value="00" type="text" name="horas" maxlength="2" />
    <span>:</span>
    <input value="00" type="text" maxlength="2" />
    <span>:</span>
    <input value="00" type="text" maxlength="2" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div {
    width:6em;
    margin:1rem auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    font-size:36px;
}
input {
    width:1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I need the text to increase or decrease, according to the resolution or size of the browser.

Comment: The you would need to use media queries to change the font size..just like any other HTML.

Comment: That's another question. You can easily find the answer on SO by making a simple search for "media queries".